# Javascript (jquery) variable adding values instead of replacing, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

dear friends.

I've found some case i cant understand.

Here is an example - whenether you choose 1,2,3,4 or 5 button, betPrice takes normally 1 value.

But if you press PUT button it will tell, betPrice variable has as many values inside, as you had pressed before! Why?

If you press 1,2,3,4 or 5 button again, it will be one value again.

### Heading

```js
$('.single-place-to-bet').find('a').on('click', function() {
      var betPrice;
      betPrice = $(this).find("span[class^='bet-price']").attr('class');
      console.log(betPrice);

      $("#sendnumber").click(
        function() {
          console.log(betPrice);
          
        }
      );
      });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bet modal begin -->
</head>
<body>
<button id="sendnumber" name="sendnumber">Put</button>

<!-- bet modal end -->




<hr>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">

    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice1">
                 1
             </span>
    <span class="bet-price-1">???</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice2">
                 2
             </span>
    <span class="bet-price-2">???</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice3">
                 3
             </span>
    <span class="bet-price-3">???</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice4">
                 4
             </span>
    <span class="bet-price-4">???</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice5">
                 5
             </span>
    <span class="bet-price-5">???</span>
  </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time the function runs, your set an additionnal event listener.

For your case you can't move the event listener out of the function, so you can une jQuery off() to remove any event listener on the button then set it again.

```js
$('.single-place-to-bet').find('a').on('click', function() {
      var betPrice;
      betPrice = $(this).find("span[class^='bet-price']").attr('class');
      console.log(betPrice);

      $("#sendnumber").off().on('click',
        function() {
          console.log(betPrice);
          
        }
      );
      });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bet modal begin -->
</head>
<body>
<button id="sendnumber" name="sendnumber">Put</button>

<!-- bet modal end -->




<hr>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">

    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice1">
                 1
             </span>
    <span class="bet-price-1">???</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice2">
                 2
             </span>
    <span class="bet-price-2">???</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice3">
                 3
             </span>
    <span class="bet-price-3">???</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice4">
                 4
             </span>
    <span class="bet-price-4">???</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice5">
                 5
             </span>
    <span class="bet-price-5">???</span>
  </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime any number is pressed, it is registering a new click listener for `sendnumber` button element. Place the button click listener outside the callback function of `.single-place-to-bet` listener

```js
var betPrice;

$('.single-place-to-bet').find('a').on('click', function() {
  betPrice = $(this).find("span[class^='bet-price']").attr('class');
  console.log(betPrice);

});

$("#sendnumber").click(
  function() {
    if (betPrice) {
      console.log(betPrice);
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sendnumber" name="sendnumber">Put</button>

<!-- bet modal end -->




<hr>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">

    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice1">
        1
      </span>
    <span class="bet-price-1">???</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice2">
        2
      </span>
    <span class="bet-price-2">???</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice3">
        3
      </span>
    <span class="bet-price-3">???</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice4">
        4
      </span>
    <span class="bet-price-4">???</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="single-place-to-bet col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="result-for-final" data-numberid="choice5">
        5
      </span>
    <span class="bet-price-5">???</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. I've tried this before, but somehow  second function didn't see the betprice. Oh... it was because i've declared it inside first function...

Comment: Exactly, `betPrice` has to be declared in a common scope for the second function to see its value.

Comment: Anyway i have to run second function from first one, cause it uses its other vars, that are not listed in this example, cause it is simplified

Answer (score 0):

There are actually multiple **betPrice** variables printing themselves with **console.log()**.

This happens because you put **("#sendnumber")...** inside your **.on** event handler, creating a new event handler everytime you click the **Put** button.

Move the second event handler creator outside the first one, like below, and you should be fine:

```
$('.single-place-to-bet').find('a').on('click', function() {
    var betPrice;
    betPrice = $(this).find("span[class^='bet-price']").attr('class');
    console.log(betPrice);

    $("#sendnumber").click(
        function() {
            console.log(betPrice);
        }
    );
});
```